# when dual booting ubuntu before windows 7 what type of file system should ubuntu be set to?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have an acer that originally ran Win8 but I wanted to install Ubuntu. I did and kept it on for a while. I am now attempting to dual boot windows. I have successfully installed windows and partitioned my HDD by using GParted. However, Ubuntu will not show up in my boot menu. I am not sure of what file system to set the Ubuntu partition to in order for it to show up in my boot menu. I am afraid that I may have just overwritten it, but it is still there in the Gparted GUI. I really need some help quick!!! ):

Comment: @Avinash Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue. When I go into the ACER boot menu, it still only has two options: one is Win7, the other is a CD/DVD Drive. When I attempt to try the CD/DVD drive, it states that there is no bootable device (which is obvious) and to insert a boot disk to continue. Perhaps I need to go into the Bios and set up the boot order, but there is a password blocking me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a partition with ext4 filesystem for the installation of Ubuntu.